# Как проверить файловый дескриптор в c?

Tags: linux, c

Пишу сервер. когда клиент отключается, epoll возвращает этот файловый дескриптор. но как узнать что этот дескриптор работает или закрыл соединение. у меня на этапе чтение с него процесс останавливается и ждет новых данных, но этот из этого файла не будет данных, клиент просто отключился. как проверить на то, отключился ли клиент или нет? Это в си программировании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз Вы используете выражение "закрыл соединение", то серверный сокет должен был создаваться с флагом SOCK_STREAM. В таком случае:

> Если отправитель вызвал функцию shutdown (раздел 16.2), чтобы
>   завершить передачу данных, или если протокол поддерживает завершение
>   передачи по умолчанию и отправитель закрыл свой сокет, то функция recv
>   вернет значение 0 после получения всех данных.

"UNIX Профессиональное программирование". У. Ричард Стивенс, 2007. стр. 667